# What is the correct way to wait for user input using ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, task, server-side, pause

What would be the correct approach to implement waiting for user input triggered by server?

Let's assume following scenario:

User sends a request ->

during the execution of this request additional data OR simple confirmation is required ->

the current execution is paused, token is generated with timeout, along with content to send to client ->

on client side a pop-up appears ->

user completes required task, data is sent to server along with the token, that resumes the previous task execution with additional data provided by user.

I already implemented this using a delegate callback in new thread that awaits this token, but I don't think that's the correct approach, is there any other way to do this?

Also, I am aware that it's usually split into two actions, one for the request and other for the confirmation request, but that's impossible to do due to the system being very dynamic and most of serverside actions workflows are defined in data layer.

Comment: _most of serverside actions workflows are defined in data layer_ this can get things harder to manage. And this seems the case

Comment: Is it possible for the client to verify with the server if there are any confirmation or additional data needed before even starting the process?

Comment: @Mt. Schneiders i will try to investigate this approach, maybe I can have some container object for additional data that will be pinged back and forth and if input is required it will just ask for the data, fill this container and try again. Thanks

Comment: You should split it in two actions. Http is stateless. When you require a confirmation, just redirect the user, with all the data he passed to the request to a different view where the old data is in hidden fields and the new data is visible (or just yes/no button for confirmation). Then send the request with the additional data, and only then begin the task. don't start thread yourself, it will hurt the scalability of your app

Comment: Alternatively you could implement a saga (also know as process manager). Its an stateful object/state machine, containing data. First requests creates the saga and adds some info, including the token. The second requests loads the existing saga, passes the token and only then the process starts

Comment: Thank you @Tseng, the second approach seems even better than pinging a data container back and forth, I will probably implement that, along with timed data disposal in case the request is never completed.

Answer (score 0):

Task solved (thanks @Tseng) using a stateful object stored on server, whenever data is missing, already present data is stored, token is sent back to client, along with token a requried data keys, UI desscriptors to generate form, etc.

Request is then called again, new data is added to this stored object and the task is attempted again, either finishing successfully or prompting for more data.

Timed disposal is implemented, disposal when job is finished + storage limit per session is in place to prevent malicious overloading.

Thanks again